# Update dataframe by Comparing Date field records in a second dataframe and append new records only

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, lubridate

I want to compare the Date field of two dataframes and add only the latest records from the second one. The first dataframe has the latest records. These records are updated daily from site. The second one reads the records from a csv file that I saved from the previous day.

data I read from the internet:

```
df_new<-structure(list(DCounter = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
   CCounter = c(125L, 36L, 22L, 17L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 20L, 8L, 3L), 
   RCounter = c(24L, 33L, 34L, 50L, 33L, 21L, 62L, 10L, 20L, 31L), 
   CrCounter = c(1L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 2L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L), 
   Date = c("20/03/2020", "19/03/2020", "18/03/2020", "17/03/2020", "16/03/2020", "15/03/2020", "14/03/2020", "13/03/2020", "12/03/2020","11/03/2020")), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 10L))
```

Format the date field to be Date type and rename field

```
df_new$Date = as.Date(df_new$Date, format = "%d/%m/%y")
colnames(df_new)<-c("D","C","R","Cr","Date")

#old data- read from csv file has data from yesterday
#----------------------
#df_old <- read.csv("df_Saved.csv",header=T)

df_old<-structure(list(D = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
   C = c(6L, 12L, 7L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 20L, 8L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 10L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 17L, 15L, 6L, 5L), 
   R = c(3L,3L, 0L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
   Cr = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), 
   Date = structure(c(17L, 16L, 15L, 14L, 13L, 12L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 8L, 25L, 24L, 23L, 22L, 21L, 20L, 19L, 18L, 7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), 
   .Label = c("2/24/2020", "2/25/2020", "2/26/2020", "2/27/2020", 
"2/28/2020", "2/29/2020", "3/1/2020", "3/10/2020", "3/11/2020", "3/12/2020",
 "3/13/2020", "3/14/2020", "3/15/2020", "3/16/20", "3/17/20", "3/18/20",
 "3/19/20", "3/2/2020", "3/3/2020", "3/4/2020", "3/5/2020", "3/6/2020", "3/7/2020", "3/8/2020", "3/9/2020"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -25L))
```

Get today's date and format it

```
#--------------

dateToAdd<-format(Sys.time(), "%Y/%m/%d")

#extract ONLY updated dates
df_newExtracted<- with(df_new, df_new[(Date >= dateToAdd), ])
  if(df_old$Date[1]< df_newExtracted$Date[1] ){
      df_final<-rbind(df_newExtracted,df_old)
      cat("Add New records\n")  

}else{
     df_final<-df_old
     cat("Nothing new \n")  
}

df_final

write.csv(df_final, "df_Saved.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

I couldn't figure out the root cause of the problem, sometimes if the difference in the date one day, it works and sometimes the difference 2 days , it's not working. Sometimes if the `df_newExtracted`represent a date that has not been updated by the site like for example:  if we run the code today date and they still haven't update their records, the variable will be empty and crash all calculation.

Some suggest the issue related to writing to csv file and reading csv,which will change the format and make the file unstable, and I should use `lubridate`, that's why I have added the formatting lines.   Any suggestion ?

Comment: storing the extracted latest record based on Date comparison

Comment: because I want to add it to df_old to keep updating the records.